# Creating repeated circles x and y axis python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am looking to generate this pattern but within python:

[image: red circles and semicircles]

Here is the code I have generated which generates the 5 full circles going across:

```
def fdShape():
    win = GraphWin("pdShape",200,200)
    centre = Point(20,100)
    for x in range(5):
        circle = Circle(centre, 20)
        circle.setFill("red")
        centre = Point((centre.getX() + 40),100)
        circle.draw(win)
```

However I am completed puzzled on how to get the semi circles above and below. Anyone have any ideas? I am not sure how I would get the code to repeat along the y-axis.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What graphics module are you using? TkInter doesn't have classes with these names, and neither do PyQt/PySide, PyGtk+, wxPython… The Python wrappers for LEDA have a `GraphWin`, but no `Circle`… I'm stumped.

Comment: Hey @abarnert, this is the graphics module I am using: http://poolem.myweb.port.ac.uk/intprog/graphics.py John Zelle - Python Programming: An Introduction to Computer Science

Comment: OK, after taking a quick pass through that library, I've refined my answer a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using Python's turtle graphics that probably doesn't work the way you imagined:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen, Shape

COUNT = 5
SIZE = 400
RADIUS = SIZE / COUNT
STAMP_UNIT = 20

screen = Screen()

circle_in_square = Shape("compound")
turtle = Turtle(shape="square")
circle_in_square.addcomponent(turtle.get_shapepoly(), "white")
circle_in_square.addcomponent([(-10, 10), (-10, -10)], "black")
circle_in_square.addcomponent([(10, -10), (10, 10)], "black")

turtle.shapesize(SIZE / STAMP_UNIT * 1.01)
turtle.stamp()  # stamp background to get a border

turtle.shape("circle")
turtle.shapesize(1.0)
circle_in_square.addcomponent(turtle.get_shapepoly(), "red", "black")

screen.register_shape("squircle", circle_in_square)
turtle.shape("squircle")
turtle.shapesize(RADIUS / STAMP_UNIT)
turtle.penup()

for y in range(1 - COUNT, 1):
    for x in range(-COUNT//2 + 1, COUNT//2 + 1):
        for sign in (1, -1):
            turtle.goto(x * RADIUS, y * RADIUS/2 * sign)
            turtle.stamp()

screen.exitonclick()
```

It first creates a stamp I call a ***squircle*** which is a red circle on a white square with black borders on the top and bottom:

[image]

It then stamps out a bunch of these, side-by-side on the horizontal, 50% overlapped on the vertical:

[image]

With a little bit of outer border stamped in.  This is part of my "Better Living Through *Stamping*" series (as opposed to *drawing* which your solution and the other answer attempted.

Answer (score 1):

Without having any idea what graphics library you're using, it's hard to give a concrete answer. But there are four possibilities:

1. The library may have an `Arc` class similar to the `Circle` class, or maybe a way of restricting a `Circle` object to display just a (filled) arc, or something similar. If so, to get your semicircles, you'd use something like `Arc(centre, 20, -math.pi/2, math.pi/2)` and `Arc(centre, 20, math.pi/2, 3*math.pi/2)`.
2. The library may have a way to set an explicit bounding box to truncate any object. So, you'd do something like: `bb = circle.getBoundingBox(); bb.top = (bb.top + bb.bottom) / 2; circle.setBoundingBox(bb)`.
3. The library may not have any explicit way to do this, but may let you draw things on top of other things in the Z-order. So, first you draw the five complete circles cross the top, then you draw a big white rectangle that covers up the lower half of all the circles. (That could even give you those rectangular lines for free, if there's a way to set border color as well as fill color.)
4. The library may not have any way to do this at all, in which case you have to use a different library.

Meanwhile, for "how I would get the code to repeat along the y-axis", that's just another loop outside the one you already have. Something like this:

```
def fdShape():
    win = GraphWin("pdShape",200,200)
    centre = Point(20,100)
    for y in range(9):
        for x in range(5):
            circle = Circle(centre, 20)
            circle.setFill("red")
            centre = Point((centre.getX() + 40), centre.getY())
            circle.draw(win)
        centre = Point(20, centre.getY() + 40)
```

However, it would probably be better to just create the points from x and y instead of adding to them explicitly:

```
    for y in range(9):
        for x in range(5):
            centre = Point(x * 40 + 20, y * 40 + 60)
            circle = Circle(centre, 20)
            circle.setFill("red")
            circle.draw(win)
```

Looking at [the library link you gave in the comments](http://poolem.myweb.port.ac.uk/intprog/graphics.py), there doesn't seem to be any way to do either 1 or 2. The full documentation is in a textbook that I don't have, but there's [reference docs](http://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python) online, and the code is pretty simple. Neither `Circle` nor any of its parent classes have any way to specify an arc, or a box to truncate to. (There is a bounding box, but cutting that in half will just result in a squashed ellipse half the height of the original circle, not a semicircle.)

And presumably you're taking a course that's requiring this library, so 4 isn't an option.

Which leaves 3. That means you're actually going to have to change the loop up a bit. Something like this:

```
    for y in range(4):
        # draw row of circles y
        # draw row 8-y
        # draw rectangle y
        # draw rectangle 8-y
    # draw row of circles 4
```

Note that rectangle 3 and rectangle 5 will be the same one, so it's a bit wasteful to draw both, but I think in this case, keeping the code simpler is worth the waste. If your teacher disagrees, it should be pretty easy to figure out how to restructure the code.

Finally, speaking of restructuring the code, given that you have to do "draw row of circles" twice with different values, you should probably turn that into a function, and likewise for "draw rectangle". Then the pseudocode above turns into real code:

```
    for y in range(4):
        drawRowOfCircles(win, y)
        drawRowOfCircles(win, 8-y)
        drawRectangle(win, y)
        drawRectangle(win, 8-y)
    drawRowOfCircles(win, 4)
```

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the [turtle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html) package in python.  Within turtle you can specify a [circle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html#turtle.circle) and what range of angles to plot of it.  Of course then you just need to figure out where to center your circles and iterate to your hearts content!